# No module named django_select2

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run an example from the django-SHOP framework. Following their tutorial on running the example, I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named django_select2
```

I've installed django_select2 but it still throws the error. Any ideas?

Installing stripe through conda throws the error

> CondaValueError: too few arguments, must supply command line package specs or --file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it installed?

Please run:

```
pip install django_select2
```

If you're using anaconda, try:

```
conda install -c django_select2
```

You can also do:

```
activate /home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1
pip install django_select2
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked although now, I'm getting another unrelated error saying No module named shop_stripe

Comment: That's probably because you need to install it too. You can use the same method to install any missing module

Comment: It just did, after lots of tinkering with tho. Thanks